# How to rotated individual instance objects in geo nodes

Tags: support

I would like the skateboards to rotate as seen in the two images. However, I want them to rotate one after the other. In the image with the value, you can see that they all have the same rotation value. Here, I would like the second board to start rotating only when the first board has completed 10% of its 360-degree rotation. I have tried using GeoNodes, but I have not achieved the desired result.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: Rotation shown]

[image: Rotation shonw 2]
[image: Geo Nodes]
[image: Value Rotation]

Comment: Hello and Welcome. The Meta site is for questions about this site, the network, moderation, rules and how they work. For regular questions about Blender usage please use [Main](https://blender.stackexchange.com) instead.